# Laravel 4 pushing structurized array to model collection

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-4, eloquent, models

I have model Users and new custom collection with same fields.

```
$users = User::all();

$object = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
$object->add(
    [
        "name"=>'John',
        "status"=>"pending",
        "created_at"=> "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at"=> "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    ]
);

// Trying to pull new to the main;
$users->push($object);
```

Everyting is great, but when I'm trying to loop new collection, it is not retrieving pushed data, and throws **Undefined Propery**.

Any suggestions, please, I'm totally wasted.

Comment: btw: are you aware that laravel 4 is rotting corpse? Last release is June 1, 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a new User instance like this :

```
$users = User::all();

$newUser = new User([
        "name"=>'John',
        "status"=>"pending",
        "created_at"=> "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "updated_at"=> "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    ]);

// Trying to pull new to the main;
$users->push($newUser);
```